# Hot to add text to svg

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I use vue-svg-map and usa map.

I need to show state code (path.id) on my svg map. How can i make this?

```html
<radio-svg-map
 v-model="selectedLocation"
 :map="usa"
 :location-class="getLocationClass"
  @change="selectdLocation"
  @mouseover="pointLocation"
  @mouseout="unpointLocation"
  @mousemove="moveOnLocation"
 />
 
  import usa from "../static/usa";
  
<svg
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="192 9 1028 746"
 aria-label="Map of USA"
>
    <path
     id="AK"
     name="Alaska"
     d="M456.18,..."
    />
...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can use `<text>` SVG tag.

If you using Vue.JS it will be something like:

`<text>{{ path.id }}</text>`

More detailed about `<text>` tag you can read here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text

P.S. Your code snippet seems a little bit broken.

Comment: I tried to add   <text font-size="42.5" fill="red" ><textPath xlink:href="#AK">AK</textPath></text>  to svg file after <path Id="AK" name="Alaska" d=".."/> but it does not work

Comment: Hm... Try to put it in `<g>` tag, both `<path>` and `<text>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: I am sure problem is in 'vue-svg-map' component. But there is no guide for this question(